# With Tkinter, how to dynamically change label when a button is clicked?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, button, tkinter

Using Tkinter with Python: I need to change a label text when a button is clicked and it should be changed to original value after the button processing is done. Trying the approach below, I cannot get the text to change. What am I doing wrong?
Using grid geometry.
For the label text suing StringVar with set method to update text.

```
# one button, one label - in grid geometry - 1 row x 2 cols.
#   Button text = "Click me"
#   Label text = "Ready"
#   on clicking button:
#   while button processing going on: label text = "Processing button 1"
#   after button processing done: label text = "Ready"

import tkinter as tk
import time
from functools import partial

def btn_is_clicked(_label_strVar):
    ## change text
    _label_strVar.set(f"Processing button")
    ## processing sometihng long
    print(f"Sleeping...")
    time.sleep(3)
    ## restore text
    _label_strVar.set(f"Ready")
    print(f"Exitend command")

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x100")
n_rows = 1
n_cols = 2

## label for messages to user
lbl_msg = tk.StringVar()
lbl = tk.Label(
    master=root,
    textvariable=lbl_msg,
    bg="blue", fg="white",
    borderwidth=10,
    relief=tk.SUNKEN
    )
lbl_msg.set(f"Ready")

## button
btn = tk.Button(
    master=root,
    text=f"Click me",
    borderwidth=10,
    relief=tk.RAISED,
    command=partial(btn_is_clicked, lbl_msg)
)

## configure the grid
for r_idx in range(n_rows):
    root.rowconfigure(r_idx, weight=1, minsize=20)
    for c_idx in range(n_cols):
        root.columnconfigure(c_idx, weight=1, minsize=20)

btn.grid(
    row=0, column=0,
    rowspan=1, columnspan=1,
    sticky="nsew"
)

lbl.grid(
    row=0, column=1,
    rowspan=1, columnspan=1,
    sticky="nsew"
)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Since the tkinter mainloop is blocked by the sleep, the label won't be updated until the function returns.  Add `root.update_idletasks()` after `_label_strVar.set(f"Processing button")` to force the label update.  However time-consuming task should be executed in a thread.

Comment: Did exactly what I needed! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use time.sleep in tkinter programs. It prevents all event processing. Use `after`.
In this case both the events needed to change the text and those generated to reset it all get processed once your `time.sleep` completes. So you see no effect.

(Untested fix):

```
def btn_is_clicked(btn, _label_strVar):
    _label_strVar.set(f"Processing button")
    btn.after(1000, _label_strVar.set, "Ready")
```

Comment: Ok will test without sleep. Actual use case has some long processing happening but facing problem with label text change. Otherwise is basic approach right?